# What would be a more idiomatic version of this sentence: "You won't be the only one affected, it's all of us."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

The following is from the BBC and is about a person who finally understand cutting down forests will be very bad. So he starts planting saplings and warns other people when sees them -still doing it- not to cut down trees. He says to them:

'**You won't be the only one affected, it's all of us**'."

I wonder if this structure is idiomatic, because one side of the sentence relates to **"future"** and the other side is about **"present"**.

Instead I would say:

**"It won't be only you who will be affected, it will be all of us."**

But, when I compare them, mine sounds too wordy to say the same thing. As I am not a native speaker, I want to ask: Which one is more idiomatic?

Comment: You are (present tense) not the only one [now, present] in the group of those who will be affected, it is all of us.

Comment: IMHO this question illustrates the difference between native speakers and people who are trying to learn English later in life. The first cited example is ***from the BBC***, and it's perfectly natural phrasing. There's nothing actually *wrong* with the non-native speaker's alternative, but it's pointlessly verbose. More to the point though - Why would a non-native speaker ***cite*** text from the BBC, then ask whether ***their own*** version might be "more idiomatic"? If it came from the BBC it's almost certainly more idiomatic that a non-native Anglophone's alternative phrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I understand your point on "Why would a non-native speaker cite text from the BBC, then ask whether their own version might be "more idiomatic". I cited it and asked the question, because that citex text is not that of a native speaker's. Although the story is published on BBC, the sentence is from a person who is a non-native speaker living in the rainforest area. And his words are given in quotation marks on the web site. So, I thought as a non-native speaker, his sentence might not be proper English, which is why I wanted to ask.

Comment: Perhaps the explains why your cited speaker (who appears to be addressing *multiple* "other people" = "them") says *You won't be the only **one** affected*. If not, there's either a transcription error or his English is very poor indeed. It's all just sloppy conversation text anyway, in which context a native speaker probably wouldn't bother moving out of Present Tense: ***You're** not the only **ones** affected. **It's** all of us.*